# Why is the program printing numbers when the variable is a string?

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to write a method that will take a string like "abcd" and then print out each character twice so that the output will be "aabbccdd". So far, this is the code I have:

```
String abcd = "abcd";
    String t = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < abcd.length(); i++){
        t = t + (abcd.charAt(i) + abcd.charAt(i));
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < abcd.length(); j++){
        System.out.printf("%s\n",t);
    }
```

The code above prints out numbers and I don't understand why. Shouldn't it print out the letters since all the variables are strings?

Comment: I think that has something to do with you adding a char to another char.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variables are strings, but [`charAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-) returns a `char`, which is a kind of number, and then you're adding those numbers together, which leaves you with an `int`. Use a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead and append the result of `charAt` twice.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up doing it as you suggested. I had overlooked stringbuilder.

Answer (score 1):

See [Binary Numeric Promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) from [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html).

> When an operator applies binary numeric promotion to a pair of operands, each of which must denote a value that is convertible to a numeric type, the following rules apply, in order:
>
> 1. If any operand is of a reference type, it is subjected to unboxing conversion.
> 2. Widening primitive conversion is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
>    - If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
>    - Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float.
>    - Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted to long.
>    - **Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.**

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 0;
        float f = 1.0f;
        double d = 2.0;
        // First int*float is promoted to float*float, then
        // float==double is promoted to double==double:
        if (i * f == d) System.out.println("oops");

        // A char&byte is promoted to int&int:
        byte b = 0x1f;
        char c = 'G';
        int control = c & b;
        System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(control));

        // Here int:float is promoted to float:float:
        f = (b == 0) ? i : 4.0f;
        System.out.println(1.0 / f);
    }
}
```

For your particular use case removing the parenthesis should be enough. By using them you force char addition to happen first.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the parenthesis like this:

`t = t + abcd.charAt(i) + abcd.charAt(i);`

Otherwise the `char` values are numerically added according to their ASCII value when retrieved using `charAt(i)`.

Comment: Thank you. Looking at it, it looks like an obvious fix. Can't believe I didn't see that.

Answer (score 0):

you can change that line to

```
t += abcd.charAt(i) + (abcd.charAt(i) + "");
```

so that you can get its string value.

Answer (score 0):

public class Test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "abcd";
    String t ="";

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        t = t + s.charAt(i) + s.charAt(i);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++){
        System.out.printf("%s\n",t);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Just like this demo,you can get the String value

Answer (score 0):

Ok, straight to the code:

```
String txt = "abcd";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

char c;
for (int i = 0; i < txt.length(); i++){
    c = txt.charAt(i);
    sb.append(c).append(c);
}
System.out.printf("%s\n", sb.toString());
```

- [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) - when you are going to concatenate strings or characters, especially when concatenating long strings, use StringBuilder. It does not create a copy of the string every time, when you append.
- Character addition - [Bax's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36168029/179669) already pointed this out. [Primitive data types in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

> char: The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has
>   a minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff' (or
>   65,535 inclusive).

Which explains what you received as result of the addition.

Answer (score 0):

```
String charDouble(String str){

   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   for(int i=0; i< str.length(); i++){
     sb.append(str.chatAt(i));
     sb.append(str.charAt(i));
   }
   return sb.toString();

   //Alternatively you could just print it here.
   //System.out.println(sb.toString());

}
```